# What is the opposite of "plain housing/plain residential buildings"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Consider the expression,

> The government housing is very homogeneous. All houses are very unremarkable **plain-looking** houses.

What would be the opposite of plain looking houses? Some words, I have considered, are glamorous, luxurious. But, they don't convey the meaning I intended to.

I am looking for a word/words for houses that attract attention with their design/architecture?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use "attractive", "aesthetically pleasing", "appealing", "alluring".

There are many others [here](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/plain-looking) as well!